# Поведение агрегатов в DDD должно/может быть как поведение субъектов или должно/может быть как действия над объектами?

Tags: архитектура, проектирование, домен, entity, ddd

Приведу два примера. Опустим некоторые даже важные вещи из DDD сейчас, примеры призваны показать суть вопроса.

Как правильнее сделать с точки зрения DDD?

Есть два корневых агрегата, продавец и объявление. Продавец может  редактировать объявление в данных примерах:

1.

Если  модели должны отражать реальную бизнес логику. То именно `Seller` изменяет объявление. Те клиентский слой вызывает методы `changeAdvertName()` и `changeAdvertCost()` агрегата `Seller`. Это дает такое преимущество как скажем, проверка доступа, мы можем видеть что `Seller` может изменить только свои `Adverts`. Это первый вариант как можно сделать.

```
    //Client layer call seller.changeAdvertName(name)

    //AR Seller
    class Seller{
        adverts
        changeAdvertName(advertId, name){
            adverts[advertId].changeName(name)
        }
        changeAdvertCost(advertId, cost){
            adverts[advertId].changeCost(cost)
        }
    }

    //AR Advert
    class Advert{
        name
        cost
        changeName(name){
            this.name = name
        }
        changeCost(cost){
            this.cost = cost
        }
    }
```

2.

Другой вариант, это где клиентский слой будет вызывать `changeName` и `changeCost` напрямую у агрегата `Advert`. Такую реализацию я чаще вижу в разных примерах.

```
    //Client layer call advert.changeName(name)

    //AR Advert
    class Advert{
        name
        cost
        changeName(name){
            this.name = name
        }
        changeCost(cost){
            this.cost = cost
        }
    }
```

Оба ли вариант допустимы в DDD? И какой из них более правильный и логичный с точки зрения DDD?

Comment: Мне уже ответили на данный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927675/behavior-of-aggregate-roots-in-ddd-should-be-as-actor-or-not

Comment: Тогда интерпретируйте этот ответ сюда, дабы принести пользу. Иначе от этого вопроса мало толку

Comment: DDD это настолько широкий подход, что его можно приписать к чему угодно. Что подсказывает здравый смысл, так это то что `changeAdvertCost` и `changeAdvertName` явно лишние методы (так как они не привносят своей собственной логики) - гораздо логичнее бы смотрелся метод `getAdvert(id)` в классе `Seller`. А лишнего должно быть как можно меньше - чтобы не рассеивать внимание тех, кто будет заниматься этим кодом, и соответственно ускорить разработку + отдалить момент коллапса.

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения DDD([blue book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321125215), [red book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321834577)) более верен вариант № 2.

Поведение агрегата должно быть выражено командами. Вызывая команду агрегата - мы приказываем ему сменить свое состояние.

ООП парадигма не прямо соответсвует грамматике разговорного языка. Мы обычно пишем "Продавец изменяет объявление". Субъект изменяет объект. Но в грамматике ООП объекты изменяют свое собственное состояние в ответ на внешние команды.
List.addItem(...) - мы не изменяем список, мы посылаем списку команду: "список, поменяй свое состояние".

Какими должны быть агрегаты? (в контексте данного вопроса)

1. Являться границей согласованности данных.

> При разработке АГРЕГАТОВ может возникнуть желание создать структуру, допускающую обход по глубоким графам объектов, но назначение этого шаблона другое. В книге [Эванс] утверждается, что один АГРЕГАТ может содержать ссылки на КОРНИ других АГРЕГАТОВ. Однако мы должны иметь виду, что это не помещает АГРЕГАТ, на который ссылаются, в границы согласованности АГРЕГАТА, который на него ссылается. Ссылка не порождает один целостный агрегат. Вместо него существуют два или больше агрегатов.

Источник: [IDDD В. Вернон](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321834577) 
Вон Вернон в своей IDDD советует ссылаться на другие агрегаты по их идентификаторам.

2. Должны стараться избегать внедрения зависимостей, в том числе от других агрегатов.

Согласно IDDD нужно стараться избегать зависимостей от других агрегатов, служб, репозиториев. Агрегат должен быть максимально изолирован.

Источники:

[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927675/behavior-of-aggregate-roots-in-ddd-should-be-as-actor-or-not)

[DDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321125215)

[IDDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321834577)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Моменты, которые вы отметили - самые базовые. Вы очень хорошо ответили, но проявлю немного наглости. Хотелось бы капнуть немного глубже и практичнее. Если всё объяснять теоретически, то на книгу потянет. Поэтому попрошу, если получится, сделать update к ответу, где показать структуру агрегата на конкретном примере (описываю в следующем комментарии).

Comment: Задачка: Фирма ООО "Зоо-Агрегат" имеет сеть зоопарков по всей нашей стране. Особенность этих зоопарков заключается в том, что в каждом из таковых могут присутствовать только обезьяны и слоны. Причем они гуляют на специальных площадках и на них вешаются датчики, которые сообщают координаты. Если получится, **привести пример агрегата "зоопарк"**, в котором оперируем следующими данными: Датчик, Слон, его инфо, Обезьяна, её инфо, площадка (2D, то есть в плоском пространстве, для простоты прямоугольная). Если что, то извините за наглость, может быть меня не туда занесло.

Comment: Соответственно должна быть возможность чтения и записи всех данных. Чтение - всех данных, запись - всех данных кроме данных  датчиков о координатах.

Comment: @AndreyK. Нужно начать с того, почему вы решили, что "Зоопарк" у вас должен быть агрегатом? Редко оправдано делать агрегат таким большим. Мне кажется вы рассматриваете паттерн агрегат, больше как технический инструмент, хотя в первую очередь это инструмент моделирования предметной области. И начинать как раз нужно с моделирования вашей предметной области. В вашем комментарии недостаточно информации для того, чтобы понять как лучше смоделировать.
К тому же не совсем ясно, вы хотите понять как смоделировать поведение в сущностях, или просто описать какие должны быть сущности?

Comment: @AndreyK. Можете описать детальнее предметную область того, что вам нужно?

Comment: Ответ единственный и конкурс закончился => с благодарностью за участие делаю release стольника. Простой агрегат имею представление, как делать, захотелось увидеть более сложный. Вы говорите, что в первую очередь агрегат это инструмент моделирования предметной области. Но разве нет такого, что DDD реализуется на практике и агрегат имеет техническую имплементацию? Простите, честно говоря, я зря у вас хочу отнять время. Особого смысла отвечать нет, т.к. нет конкретной задачи. Но если кинете сюда какую-нибудь ссылочку с понятной реализацией не самого простого агрегата, то будет круто!

Comment: В принципе, зоопарк могу вынести в отдельный вопрос, если не хватит у меня силы воли сдержаться.

Comment: Вы сказали, что "не совсем ясно, вы хотите понять как смоделировать поведение в сущностях, или просто описать какие должны быть сущности". Конечно, агрегат должен содержать логику, но имел ввиду показать его вид вкратце, чтобы иметь представление. То есть, структуру, может быть название каких-нибудь методов. Но, действительно, это должно пойти в другой вопрос, и по-хорошему, должен сам представить свою версию, чтобы было понятнее что имел ввиду.